# Загрузка объекта из xml

Tags: python, xml

Мне надо чтобы из файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages>
    <message>
        <title>Заголовок</title>
        <text>Текст сообщения</text>
      </message>
</messages>
```

получилось такое

```
object.message[0].title
```

Не могу найти готового решения.
Буду благодарен, если подскажете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[python-simplexml](https://github.com/joestump/python-simplexml)

> **Overview**
>
> When I started working in Python I'd heard rumors that parsing XML was kind of a pain in the ass. Coming from PHP I had SimpleXML that worked perfectly fine for 99% of the XML parsing I had to do. When it finally came to needing to parse some simplistic XML documents I decided to write this small wrapper around ElementTree.
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> from simplexml import parse
> xml = parse("person.xml")
> print xml.name.first
> print xml.name.last
> print xml.name["origin"]
> ```

Comment: Simplexml удобен, но, если это актуально: 1) его разработка застыла в 2005 и совместимости с python 3.х пока не ожидается; 2) lxml по тестам показывает лучшую скорость парсинга, это заметно будет на файлах в несколько Мб.

Comment: Там же простейшая обертка из [геттеров](https://github.com/joestump/python-simplexml/blob/master/simplexml.py), что там разрабатывать еще :)

Comment: Согласен, особо нечего. Скорее разрабатывать надо в сторону повышения скорости. Вот сравнение LXML с xml.etree.cElementTree (xml.etree.ElementTree) http://blog.behnel.de/index.php?p=235

Answer (score 3):

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('example.xml')
raws = tree.xpath('//message')
for raw in raws:
    print raw.xpath('title')[0].text
```

если элемент только один

```
raws = tree.xpath('//message/title')
print raws[0].text
```